# Opengl es 2.0 Android: GLSurfaceView создание нового Renderer

Tags: android, opengl

Задача такова. Имеется 2 объекта `Renderer`

1. `LoadingRender extends Renderer`
2. `MainRender extends Renderer`

В `LoadingRender` я просто вывожу надпись на экран "Загрузка", класс очень быстро загружается и я вывожу его на экран первым.
`MainRender` очень долго грузится, там много HD картинок.
По этому я сперва в `GLSurfaceView` устанавливаю `LoadingRender`. После того как надпись загрузки вышла мне нужно **создать** `MainRender` и **установить** его в `GLSurfaceView`.

Как это можно сделать? В каком месте, как бы я не пробовал, выходят разнообразные ошибки.

Или, есть ли возможность сделать так. Создать нужные ресурсы: вывести их на экран и создать остальные ресурсы?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю зачем вы вообще используете 2 рендера. Почему не загрузить сначала текстуры для экрана заставки, отобразить их на экране, а затем догружать остальные текстуры ?

Comment: Ну вот что бы не задавать таких вопросов желательно дочитать все до конца, тогда бы вы увидели что я написал: "Или, есть ли возможность сделать так. Создать нужные ресурсы: вывести их на экран и создать остальные ресурсы?". Возможно вы бы тогда дали правильный ответ вместо того что бы недоумевать, над тем зачем же я использую 2 рендера. И тянуть время....

Comment: Нет вы простите мое недоумение, но оно никуда и не делось. Я не понимаю что вам может мешать создавать ресурсы вывести их, и загружать оставшиеся. Загрузил одну текстуру, выводишь используешь, грузишь следующую так же как загрузил первую. В чем проблема то ?

Comment: Вы загружаете текстуру: glActiveTexture, glBindTexture, GLUtils.texImage2D, все используете рисуете, дальше так же остальные загружаете glActiveTexture, glBindTexture, GLUtils.texImage2D , нет же никакого условия что надо все текстуры прям одновременно загрузить. Потому у меня и непонимание, я не пытаюсь как-то глумится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ. У `GLSurfaceView` есть метод `queueEvent`. В нем создается Runnable объект и удаляются и устанавливаются необходимые ресурсы